# TYPO3 8.7 EXT:form - Flash messages not shown in finisher until refresh page

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I created a custom finisher for EXT:form. Among other things, my finisher has to show a flash message:

```
  class CreateRequestActionFinisher extends \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Finishers\AbstractFinisher
  {
    // Validations ...
    $flashMessage = $this->objectManager->get(
      FlashMessage::class,
      'Everything is fine.', 
      'Thanks', 
      \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::OK, 
      true
    );
    $this->finisherContext->getControllerContext()->getFlashMessageQueue()->addMessage($flashMessage);
  }
```

My problem is that, in frontend, my flash message does not appear inmediately when I send my form. When I refresh my browser page (sending my form twice), my flash message appears. ¿What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: maybe redirect after wards? not sure (to same page maybe)

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround for TYPO3 v8.7**:
I think this is based on [this open issue](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/72703) regarding caching of flash messages. As a workaround, I currently use this additional finisher (last one in finisher array) to get it working properly:

```
-
    options:
      pageUid: '1' # uid of the page with the form
      additionalParameters: 'no_cache=1'
    identifier: Redirect
```

**TYPO3 v9.5.6 and newer:**
I think that this problem has now been solved because of [this patch](https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/60586) and a workaround is no longer necessary.

Comment: Finisher still wont work when redirect to another / the same page. :/